# std::enable_if based on variadic template existence

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, sfinae

I want to create object creator class that would take ClassType and its constructor arguments as a template arguments.

In basics my code would look like this:

```
template<typename ClassType, typename ... Args>
class ClassCreator : public ClassType
{
    std::tuple<Args ...> args_;
public:
    template <typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args)!=0>::type>
    ClassCreator(Args ... args) : args_(std::make_tuple(args ...)), ClassType(args ...){}

    template <typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args)==0>::type>
    ClassCreator() : ClassType(){}

    template <typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args)!=0>::type>
    ClassType getObject() const
    {
        return ClassType(std::get<sizeof...(Args)>(args_) ... );
    }

    template <typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args)==0>::type>
    ClassType getObject() const
    {
        return ClassType();
    }
};
```

With `std::enable_if` guarding to avoid `std::get<0>` from empty `tuple`.

I'm using it with sample class:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(){}
    A(int firstInt, int secondInt){}
};

int main()
{
    ClassCreator<A> creatorATrivial();
    ClassCreator<A, int, int> creatorA(1, 2);
    A aTrivial = creatorATrivial.getObject();
    A a = creatorA.getObject();
}
```

And I get tons of errors.
Do I understand `sizeof...` operator correctly?
Is `std::get<sizeof...(Args)>(args_) ...`  a valid way to unpack a `tuple`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that SFINAE is only **n**ot **a**n **e**rror in the *immediate context* of the substitution. In your example here:

```
template<typename ClassType, typename ... Args>
class ClassCreator : public ClassType
{
    template <typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args)!=0>::type>
    ClassCreator(Args ... args)
```

`Args...` isn't in the immediate context of the constructor, so that substitution will be performed immediately and the function instiated will be either `enable_if<true>::type` or `enable_if<false>::type`, the latter being ill-formed.

Also this:

```
return ClassType(std::get<sizeof...(Args)>(args_) ... );
```

is ill-formed. The second `...` doesn't have a pack to expand. The usual way around this is with the index sequence trick. With C++17, we also have [`std::apply`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply), which in this case would be:

```
return std::apply([](auto const&... elems){ return ClassType(elems...); },
    args_);
```

---

The simplest way to do a class creator to store arguments and then pass them up would be:

```
template <class T>
class ClassCreator {
    std::function<T()> creator;

public:
    // as improvements, add perfect forwarding
    template <class... Args,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<T, Args...>::value, int> = 0>
    ClassCreator(Args... args) {
        creator = [=]{ return T(args...); };
    }

    T getObject() const {
        return creator();
    }
};

ClassCreator<A> creatorATrivial();
ClassCreator<A> creatorA(1, 2); // no <int, int> necessary
A aTrivial = creatorATrivial.getObject();
A a = creatorA.getObject();
```